# Pass payload in GET request React fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a react/node application and I was trying to pass a value which I get from user input to the nodejs api to call a separate api (Instagram API)

I want to attach an object to req.body from React app. I want to do something like this:

```
app.get('/hashtags', (req,res) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.body.tag);
});
```

This is my responsible react app code for the above node request:

```
handleChange(e){
   const searchtag = 'hello';

   fetch('/hashtags', {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       Accept: 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
       tag: searchtag,
     }),
   })
}
```

I'm calling `handleChange` function when I click a button.
As for the above code I need my node api to call `/hashtags` with `req.body.tag = 'hello'` (as I'm passing `'hello'` from reactjs).

But this gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

If this can't be done this way: How can I attach an object to node api `req.body` from my react application?

Comment: Use a POST request, get can't have a body.

Comment: @KoenS But it's possible to pass data in get request in Angular right ?

Comment: @KoenS this is technically not true, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @JulienAmbos yeah ok, it's possible but you shouldn't do it. :-)
ThidasaParanavitharana you should pass the tag as a querystring, like shyam is doing in his answer.

Comment: there a lot problem with `fetch` better use `request` and `when` combination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass string search tag why you are passing it in `body`. As per `REST` pass it in the url like this

```
 handleChange(e){
    const searchtag = 'hello';

    fetch('/hashtags/' + searchtag, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
     ),
    })
  }
```

Comment: Yes, we can only able to send as params, but not as body, if you do so you will get TypeError: Body not allowed for GET or HEAD requests in fetch, I hope the same thing will happen in axios as well.

Comment: Sometimes you need to pass a lot of data and a url only goes up to 2048 characters. I guess REST isn't that great

Comment: You never need to pass that much data in a GET request, they're not supposed to handle large amounts of data. Generally if a lot of data is being sent over, it's for storing server side, so a PUT or POST should be used.

Comment: Also, you can compress and/or encrypt the data sent in a URL as part of a GET request, which would make the data more compact and, if encrypted, more secure.

Answer (score -1):

```
axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${api.course}`,
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('accessToken')}` },
        data:{'category': "Design"}
    })
```

Comment: Please add some details about why you suggested this and how this is supposed to work.